# I tried using webdriver manager but i keep getting this error

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver-manager

I tried selenium automation with webdriver but I keep getting errors. Please help me fix the problem

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep

browser = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("https://python.org")
```

the Error I received:

```
File "C:\Users\LUCKY-PC\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\automation\selenium_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

  File "C:\Users\LUCKY-PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\chrome.py", line 4, in <module>
    from webdriver_manager import utils

  File "C:\Users\LUCKY-PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\utils.py", line 8, in <module>
    import requests

  File "C:\Users\LUCKY-PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl

  File "C:\Users\LUCKY-PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 109, in <module>
    orig_util_SSLContext = util.ssl_.SSLContext

AttributeError: module 'urllib3.util' has no attribute 'ssl_'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with  `ChromeDriverManager().install()`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get("https://python.org")
```

Answer (score -1):

It's better if you download the chrome driver and then provide the chrome driver path to code.

Go to your chrome browser and type `chrome://settings/help`. From here you can find your chrome version.

Then go to https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads to download a chrome driver that matches your chrome version.

Now give the path to of that driver in the code below.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

class Driver_Class(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, driver_path, teardown=False):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        self.options = Options()
        self.options.headless = False
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=self.driver_path,options=self.options)

        self.options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        self.options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')

        self.teardown = teardown
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path

        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def get_driver(self):
        return self.driver

driverObj = Driver_Class("chrome_driver_path")
driver = driverObj.get_driver()
```

Now you can use this driver for the rest of your program.